# Jquery height() set using imagesloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the position of a menu beneath a slider that is dynamically generating the height, so I've used [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to load my jquery last and all is well in every browser except safari where it retrieves the height of the slider set in the back-end and not the height of the image which is dynamically generated depending on page size. this is only occurring in safari.... 
Here is the javascript to position the menu:

```
$.browser.safari = ($.browser.webkit && !(/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())));
if ($.browser.safari) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        var $container = $('.ls-wp-fullwidth-container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height() - 50;
            $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
        });
    });
} else {
    $(window).load(function () {
        var $container = $('.ls-wp-fullwidth-container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-helper").height();
            $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
        });
    });
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height() + 40;
    $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
});
```

The slider that is being used is anything slider I'm using a themeforest theme named cleanspace and running wordpress 3.5.1. 
I've tried using `$(window).bind("load",function(){` to load the jquery last and `$.browser.safari = ($.browser.webkit && !(/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())));
if ($.browser.safari) {`

 to detect the browser which works fine on pc but fails on mac, so I'm left with the first code pasted here and await any help with baited breath. 
NOTE: the if statement here is un-needed if safari would load my jQuery after the slider images...

Comment: As a sidenote, I believe $.browser was actually deprecated, most likely because it was considered a terrible idea to use it ?

Comment: Thank @adeneo you I did note that, I've also tried
 `if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {alert('Its Safari');}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around I'm guessing it's not the best anwser and would be happy to hear better suggestions, basically I've placed a timer on the function to load like so:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')     == -1) {
      $(window).load(function() {
           setTimeout(function(){
             var $container = $('.ls-wp-fullwidth-helper');
               $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                  var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-helper").height() ;
                  $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
               });
           }, 2000);
        });
       }
else {
      $(window).load(function() {
       var $container = $('.ls-wp-fullwidth-helper');
       $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
         var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-helper").height();
         $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
       });
      });
     }
 $(window).resize(function(){
   var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-helper").height() + 40;
   $(".menu_wrap").css('top', height);
 });
```